# I'm trying to input a simple math expression in the form 1 + 2

Tags: c++, math, operators

I need to set up a simple calculator that will input  and provide the output. I know I can use conditions to make it work once I have the variables saved but I can't save the variables in the way I need them to be.

```
#include <iostream>
using   namespace std;

int main(){
    int n1;
    int n2;
    char opr;
    cout<<"Enter an expression to evaluate: ";
    cin>> n1>> opr >>n2;  //my input is <1 + 2>

    cout<<n1<<endl;
    cout<<opr<<endl;
    cout<<n2<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I would expect the output to be:
1
+
2

but it comes out as:
1
0
6422368

Comment: Your `cin` expects an `int`, but you input `<`. It has failed to extract anything and all your variables are unitialized (they can have any random value).

Comment: Is your input really `<1 + 2>` or is it `1 + 2`? Makes a big difference.

Comment: I'll keep saying this forever. Users don't type *integers* into a console program.   They type *characters and strings* that are to be interpreted as integers. Assume the user will type anything and parse it accordingly and check for errors.

Comment: @selbie Good advice but beyond most newbies.

Comment: Use your debugger to see what's happening.  You'll likely see that `opr` has a space in it.

Comment: Making `opr` a `string` instead of a `char` is likely to fix it for this specific input.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your input is this `<1 + 2>`. You've written code that would work if your input was `1 + 2` but it isn't so you need to change the code.

This is one way that will work with the given input.

```
int n1, n2;
char opr, lt, gt;
cout<<"Enter an expression to evaluate: ";
cin >> lt >> n1 >> opr >> n2 >> gt;  //my input is <1 + 2>
```

The `lt` and `gt` variables are there just to read in the `<` and `>` characters in your input.